# How to click on radio input in image form in cypress. The mousepointer changes to handtool on hovering over the image

Tags: javascript, triggers, radio-button, cypress

I am using the below angular website
[https://symptomate.com/diagnosis/#0-66'](https://symptomate.com/diagnosis/#0-66%27)
I am trying to click on radio input in image form in cypress. The mousepointer changes to handtool on hovering over the image
cy.get('input[value="direct"]').parent().then(function($textvalue){

```
        if
            ($textvalue.text()=="Myself")
            cy.wrap($textvalue).invoke('show',{force:true}).trigger('mouseover',{force:true}).dblclick({force:true})
        
    })
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot too, just so that it’s clear which page of the form you’re having issues with?

Comment: If u take the test and click on next , aftr 2 pages  you will see a question page with 2 image icons , named " Myself"  and "someone else". I dont see an option to attach a file here , so i am not attaching any screenshot